# Method and class on Java

Tags: java, class

I'm writing a Java program that has some classes in it. I have one class that is `Rectangle.java` and the other `Circle.java`. On `Rectangle.java` I'm doing a method to compare the area of the rectangle and the circle. It's called `public boolean compare(Circle C)`.

When I call the method on `Principal.java` I declare `Rectangle R = new Rectangle()`,  `Circle C = new Circle()`, and then `R.compare(C)`.

My question is, inside of `public boolean compare(Circle C)` do I need to call another time `Rectangle R = new Rectangle()` to compare `R.areaRectangle()` with `C.areaCircle()`, or there is another way to do it?

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: Show your code (a few consecutive lines).

Comment: No, when you call `R.compare(C)` you should be comparing area of `R` rectangle on which you called `compare` method with area of `C` circle. To invoke `areaRectangle` inside `compare` method simply use `this.areaRectangle()` or even `areaRectangle()` (`this.` will be added implicitly by compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `R.compare(C)` you do not need to call `Rectangle R = new Rectangle()` inside `compare` function. Just use the R reference you already have (it is the `this` keyword)

Answer (score 0):

You seem new to java , you only need this key word

```
        this.areaRectangle();
```

For a better practice you should create an Interface "HasArea" , this interface can have both the methods compare and calculateArea,

```
      double calculateArea();
      boolean compare(HasArea obj);
```

both classes should implement this interface and its methods so in your Rectangle class

```
    class Rectangle implements HasArea{
       @Override
        public double calculateArea() {
         //your logic for area calculation
        }
      @Override
      public boolean compare(HasArea obj) {
         //Compare your this.calulateArea() with obj.calulateArea();  
     }
     }
```